# Enviar parametros de uma url para outras urls do site ficarem com esses mesmos parametros para uso das variaveis

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

o exemplo seria essa url abaixo com os parametros= dia=4&mes=Janeiro&ano=1948&nome=Anderson.

https://numerologia.com.br/personalizando/?dia=4&mes=Janeiro&ano=1948&nome=Anderson.

esses parametros vieram de um formulario, porem qdo eu clicar para enviar o formulario esses parametros não vai aparecer na pagina de destino. exemplo https://anumerologia.com.br/teste ela vai aparecer sem os parametros, como eu envio os parametros para ficar visivel em outras paginas

Answer (score 0):

coloca os parâmetros no atributo action do formulário:

```
<form method="POST" action="/teste?dia=4&mes=Janeiro&ano=1948&nome=Anderson">
```